# Eigenvalues $\lambda$ and $\lambda^{-1}$ of an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know that $A$ is an orthogonal matrix and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. I need to prove that $\lambda \neq 0$ and that $\lambda^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue of both $A$ and $A^\top$.

Now if $A$ is orthogonal, then $A^\top$ is its inverse matrix so we can't have an eigenvalue of $0$. Since $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ we can verify that:

$$AX = \lambda \cdot X \Leftrightarrow$$ $$\Leftrightarrow A^\top AX = \lambda \cdot A^\top X \Leftrightarrow$$ $$\Leftrightarrow X = \lambda \cdot A^\top X \Leftrightarrow$$ $$\Leftrightarrow \lambda^{-1} \cdot X = \lambda^{-1} \cdot \lambda \cdot A^\top X \Leftrightarrow$$ $$\Leftrightarrow A^\top X = \lambda^{-1} \cdot X$$.

I'm having a hard time proving the same for $\lambda^{-1}$ though...

Comment: Orthogonality implies $I = AA^\top = A^\top A$, and both matrices have the same eigenvalues, so $x = A^\top A x = \lambda A^\top x \implies A^\top x = \lambda^{-1} x.$ Similarly, $x = AA^\top x = \lambda Ax \implies Ax = \lambda^{-1}x$. So $\lambda^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue of both matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The eigenvalues of a matrix are the same as the eigenvalues of its transpose. (Look at the definition of the characteristic polynomial and note that determinants are invariant under transposes.)

Answer (score 1):

If $A_{n \times n}$ is a square matrix, then $$|A| = \lambda_{1} \times \lambda_{2} \times \lambda_{3} \times \cdot \cdot \times \ \lambda_{k}, \text{ where } k \leq n, \text{ where } \lambda_{k} \text{ are the eigenvalues of A.}$$

For any $A_{n \times n}$, $$|A| = |A^{T}|$$

Since A is orthogonal we have, $$A A^{T} =I = A^{T} A$$

It is clear that $0$ can not be the eigenvalue of an orthogonal matrix. (Why?)

$\textbf{Note:}$ If $0$ is the eigenvalue of an orthogonal matrix, A,  then $|A| = 0 = |A^{T}|$, and that means $$0 = |A A^{T}| = |A| |A^{T}| = |I| = 1$$ which is a contradiction.

$\textbf{Observe that:}$  $$|A A^{T}| = |I| =1 =|A| |A^{T}| \implies |A^{T}| = \frac{1}{\lambda_{1}}  \times \frac{1}{\lambda_{2}} \times \frac{1}{\lambda_{3}} \times \frac{1}{\lambda_{4}}  \times \cdot \cdot \times  \frac{1}{\lambda_{k}}, 
 $$

which proves that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of an orthogonal matrix, then $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of its transpose.